# Plotly Gauge Dynamic

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly.js, real-time-data

I have a problem with Plotly JS Gauge that I cannot solve and I have tried a thousand ways to solve it.

How can I use Plotly JS Gauge on real time, dynamically?

I have tried this but it does not work... ;-( :

```
<script>
    function rand() {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (250 - 0) ) + 0;
    }


    var data = [
                {
                    domain: { x: [0, 1], y: [0, 1] },
                    value: 0,
                    title: { text: "Speed" },
                    type: "indicator",
                    mode: "gauge+number"
                }
            ];

    var layout = { width: 600, height: 500, margin: { t: 0, b: 0 } };
    Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);

    var cnt = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        Plotly.extendTraces('myDiv', {value: [[rand()]]}, [0])
        if(++cnt === 100) clearInterval(interval);
    }, 300);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `Plotly.update()`:

```js
function rand() {
return Math.floor(Math.random() * (250 - 0) ) + 0;
}

var data = [
        {
            domain: { x: [0, 1], y: [0, 1] },
            value: 0,
            title: { text: "Speed" },
            type: "indicator",
            mode: "gauge+number"
        }
    ];

var layout = { width: 600, height: 500, margin: { t: 0, b: 0 } };
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);

var cnt = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function() {
Plotly.update('myDiv', {value: rand()}, {}, [0])
if(++cnt === 100) clearInterval(interval);
}, 800);
```

```html
<head>
 <!-- Load plotly.js into the DOM -->
 <script src='https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
 <div id='myDiv'><!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV --></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The gauge range will move all over the place when updating if it's not fixed in the settings.
Use the property 'gauge' in the data object for this :

```
gauge: {axis:{range: [null, 100]}}
```

This, for example, sets it to a minimum of 0 and a maximum of 100.